# Can code-first auto-create triple primary key relational table?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, relational-database, code-first

Let's take as an example 3 entities being **page** (a webpage), a **link** and an **area**. The relations go as follow.

Page *----* Link *----* Area

Which textually means :
• A page has many links
• A link can be in many page
• A link can be in many areas
• An area can contain many links

Which means, if I am not mistaking would require 4 tables. 3 for each entity and one relational table that would contain the the primary keys of each entities.

Is there a way to generate this kind of table with code-first?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no.  A junction table does not have to have primary keys at all.  It just needs foreign keys.  If you want to make them primary keys, you can, but it does not need to be.

Second, there's no such thing as 3 primary keys.  There can only be one primary key, but it may span several columns.  This is called a Composite Primary Key.  You would only need a primary key if you need to uniquely identify each row.  I typically use either no primary key, or i use a synthetic primary key (if i have a payload in the join table).

Third, No.  What you are describing would use 5 tables.  Page, Link, Area, PageLink, and LinkArea.  Area does not relate to Page in the model you present, other than through Link.

EDIT: I don't think you have thought through your data model thoroughly.  Can an Area be in many pages?  Or is an Area only in one page?  Can a Link be in both pages and areas?

EDIT: based on your comments, what you want is this then.

```
Page *---* Link *---* Area 
 *----------------------*
```

This requires 6 tables. Page, Link, Area, PageLink, PageArea, AreaLink

Comment: For second point, sorry for misexplanation, what I meant was in fact, composite primary key. I'm not quite sur what is a synthetic primary key though.

Comment: third point. Technically the area, is an area in the page. Which means that a link can be in an area of a page. But I dont necessairly want to go through the area table to know on which page is the link.

Comment: @Burnzy - Synthetic is just a column that's just a number, typically auto-incremented as an Identity field.

Comment: yes an area can be in many page. And yes link can be in a page and in an area. Because the area is in the page.

Comment: @Burnzy - No, because a link is in an area and an area is in a page, that doesn't mean the link is in the page (in the data model at least).  If a link cannot be outside of an area, there is no reason to relate the page to the link.

Comment: I get your point, however, just thinking about an optimized way to associate a link and a page. (reduced data access)

Comment: @Bunzy - I don't see the problem.  You have to load the area, and therefore the links anyways, so you should already have the data.

Comment: The problem is that I don't necessarily want to know the area to get the link, I want to be able to make a direct relation with page and links or with area and links but also with page, area and links at the same time.

Comment: I get the concept. But what I don't understand is why can't you simply have a 4 tables being Page, Area, Link and page_area_link having a composite primarykey

Comment: @Burnzy - Because many to many's don't work that way.  And, it isn't really what you want.  Consider this.  You want to lookup a link between page and link, well, there will be as many links as there are areas then, so you would have to discrimate based on area.  a 3-way junction create x * y * z permutations, what you want is x * Y + x * z + y * z

Answer (score 1):

### Architecture

Yes, actually.  You could implement this using a unified architecture where every object has a unique entry with a unique ID in an objects table.  It would also be extensible so you can add additional object types into the relation later by adding a single new table for each object type.

Any other architecture other than what I'm about to describe would require exponential growth in the number of tables to add additional relations to all existing object types.

**Table 1**: **"ObjectTypes"**.  This table would store a list of the types of objects you have.  It would have three records with names "Page", "Link", and "Area".

- **ID** int (identity)
- **Name** nvarchar(50)

**Table 2**: **"Objects"**.  This table would store object instances with unique 64-bit IDs that identify each object's type and give the object a unique human-readable name or description.  The database engine handles the uniqueness for you, simply by setting the ID field as an identity column.  This is ideal, because it makes it easy to implement any kind of system that would require unique object IDs, such as a permissions system for controlling access to particular pages, links, areas, etc.

- **ID** bigint identity
- **Type** int (foreign key to ObjectTypes.ID table)
- **Name** nvarchar(200)

**Table 3**: **"ObjectRelationships"**.  This table represents relationships between any two objects of any type.  If it was a strict hierarchy, where an object would have only one parent at a time, then you could actually make it a temporal hierarchy by adding a time stamp field and creating a view that selects the most recent entry for each object.  In your case, since you have objects that can belong to multiple other objects at the same time, a strict temporal hierarchy is not necessary; but it's also flexible enough that you could store, for some objects, a single relation per object, and still have an intact temporal hierarchy for a subset of object types.  For bi-directional relationships, two records would be required where the ObjectID and RelatedObjectID are swapped. Note that other architectures would also require two records, just in two separate tables.  Alternatively, you could simply treat a single entry as a bi-directional relationship, but it would affect how you write and interpret queries.

- **ObjectID** bigint (foreign key to Objects.ID); also would recommend a clustered index on this field
- **RelatedObjectID** bigint (foreign key to Objects.ID); also would recommend treating this is a directional relationship as ParentObjectID or ContainerObjectID, and you can still add reverse relations for bi-directional relationships
- **[Timestamp]** datetime (SQL Server datetime2(7))

**Tables 4 through 2^32**: **"Pages"**, **"Links"**, **"Areas"**, etc., etc., etc.  These three or more tables each store information unique to a specific object type.  The wonderful thing about this architecture, is that you need add only a single table for each new object type (along with a new record in the ObjectTypes table), because there is always a single table that stores your object relationships.

### Querying the Data

If you want to find all links in a page, you could query for direct relationships between pages and links like so:

```
select L.* from Links L
inner join ObjectRelationships R on R.ObjectID = L.ID
where R.RelatedObjectID = @pageID;
```

or you could find all links in a page indirectly related through areas like so:

```
--//view LinkRelationships = select * from Links L inner join ObjectRelationships R on R.ObjectID = L.ID
--//view AreaRelationships = select * from Areas A inner join ObjectRelationships R on R.ObjectID = A.ID

select L.* from LinkRelationships L
inner join AreaRelationships A on L.RelatedObjectID = A.ObjectID
inner join Pages P on P.ID = A.RelatedObjectID
where P.ID = @pageID;
```

Assuming you store bi-directional relationships (requires two records per relationship, swapping the ObjectID and RelateObjectID values), you could find all pages that contain a particular link.  As I mentioned, other architectures would also require two records, just in two separate tables.

```
select P.* from Pages P
inner join ObjectRelationships R on R.RelatedObjectID = P.ID
where R.ObjectID = @linkID;
```

This architecture is very flexible and very efficient in terms of storage space (great for avoiding disk I/O bottlenecks), but it requires you to be comfortable with performing joins and thinking of relationships as different "levels" in an hierarchy as demonstrated by the *Level views in the example query.  I actually create these views to simplify queries and make them more understandable.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with "code-first", until I read this, so I'm including a link in case anyone else is unfamiliar with it: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: It's indeed an interresting but I'm wondering how easy it will be to implement this with code-first. It's a good approach if you plan on having many further customization, but it kinda goes against the EF/Code-first approach.

Comment: @Triynko - By doing this, you lose almost all of the benefits from navigational properties, lookups, etc..  It's also questionable whether this violates various forms of normalization, and nullifies the benefits of constraints and foreign keys.